# Check if table has updated than do anything else

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am looking for a possibility in PHP to check the last update time of a table.
An example in pseudo code.

If table XY has updated within the last 30 seconds, than echo "ABC", else "do nothing".

The table contains only one entry which will be updated from time to time.
Now I want a mysql statement (as you can see above) which queries whether this table entry has been updated or not in combination with a "than-statement".

I would appreciate any hint

Tobi

Answer (score 1):

Add column `date_updated` which is a timestamp type. Check if current datetime exceeds 30 seconds, if yes, do 1, if no, do 2.